# sqlite3 got syntax error while executing vacuum in a trigger

Tags: sqlite, vacuum

I'm using sqlte3.8.8, trying to create a trigger to clean old data. Here is the SQL that I put in:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "main"."NewTrigger" AFTER INSERT ON "historydata"
BEGIN
    delete from historydata where id in (select id from historydata order by id limit 100000);
  vacuum;
END;
```

But I got Syntax error on "vacuum;".However, it works fine in sqlite command line.

Is it the case that "vacuum" cannot be used in a trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) shows that only UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE/SELECT statements are allowed in a trigger body.